# Image cropping from UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` with size (0,0,414,471). The image with size (0,0,1236,1242) is displayed with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` mode in the `UIImageView`. So the image is nicely displayed. Then I make a rectangle (0,0,100,100) on the image and I like to crop it. Even though the rectangle covered (100,100) on the `UIImageView`, on the actual image size, (100,100) does not cover the size as shown on the `UIImageView`. So I make xratio (actual width/display width) and yratio(actual height/display height), then I multiply the rectangle size, to all x,y,width and height of the rectangle. This approach looks like I can crop the area as close as possible as shown on the `UIImageView`. But still have a bit of area offset and distortion. What could be the best way to crop in this scenario?
My code is shown below

```
- (void)saveCroppedImage:(UIImage *)image withcroppedRectangle:(CGRect)clippedRect
{
    float xratio = image.size.width/displayWidth;
    float yratio = image.size.height/displayHeight;
    // Crop logic
    clippedRect.origin.x *= xratio;
    clippedRect.origin.y *= yratio;
    clippedRect.size.width *= xratio;
    clippedRect.size.height *= yratio;

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], clippedRect);
    UIImage * croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    NSString *imageName =@"Documents/";
    imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:[CurrentToddlerProfile getUserID]];
    imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    // Write image to PNG
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(croppedImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
    // Create file manager
//    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
//    NSError *error;
//    // Point to Document directory
//    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
//    // Write out the contents of home directory to console
//    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);

}
```

Comment: Try to use floor() in your calculations, to avoid partial pixel alignment, especially for the origin.

Comment: No floor() removes the decimal points and have more error in cropped area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need two ratios ? If you want your image to have the right proportions, you should use only one ratio.

If you need to fill a rectangle ( Even if UIImageView does it for you ), then first compute the ratio on x axis. Compute the scaled height using this ratio, if it is smaller than the height you need to cover, then compute the ratio on y axis.

Finally, the ratio just computed is the one to use to scale your image.

Comment: Yeah you are good. For width and height, don't need two ratios. But for x and y positions i still need two ratios. That x,y position multiplication has some position offset.

Comment: yep - that's right. But then your image has the expected size and ratio, no?

By the way, I'd rather have used the center of the image as reference than the top-left corner.

If you use different ratios to scale your offset and your dimensions, I'm not sure it can work..

Comment: yeah thanks, center is a kind of top-left corner added with a fixed interval. I think it will be the same. Because my rectangle is square.

Comment: But your source image is not. I don't think center is not "a kind of…". It is center. No matter rectangle or square. 
Then maybe the top-left corner is a kind of center added with a fixed interval :D ! Joke appart, maybe you can try to simply calculate your square size, center it on original image, and do the crop.

Comment: How come you are so good. Yeah true, source image is not. now no offset.